# Upload Image to Server and Store in MySQL Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, image-upload

I have read a lot of posts about uploading image to the server but i still have a problem. The image was succesfully stored in my folder path, but when i opened the table of my database in phpmyadmin the image wasn't store in there.

My question is, how can I modifiy the code to save the image path additionally into a MySql database, after the image is succesfully stored in destination folder? Please help on this.

For completition I am showing my current code to upload the image to the server:

upload.java :

```
 @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

         if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

         }
        }
          public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                 String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                 int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 return cursor.getString(column_index);
             }

        public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


           String fileName = sourceFileUri;

              HttpURLConnection conn = null;
              DataOutputStream dos = null;  
              String lineEnd = "\r\n";
              String twoHyphens = "--";
              String boundary = "*****";
              int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
              byte[] buffer;
              int maxBufferSize = 1 * 512 * 512; 
              File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

              if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                pDialog.dismiss(); 

                Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                     messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                    }
                }); 

                return 0;

              }
              else
              {
                try { 

                   // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of  maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                      dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                     }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                      + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                    if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                              String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" D:/food/adminweb/foto_berbagi_masakan/";
                              messageText.setText(msg);
                                 Toast.makeText(Berbagi_Resep.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                         });                
                    }    

                    //close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

               } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                   pDialog.dismiss();  
                   ex.printStackTrace();

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                           Toast.makeText(Berbagi_Resep.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });

                   Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
               } catch (Exception e) {

                   pDialog.dismiss();  
                   e.printStackTrace();

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                           Toast.makeText(Berbagi_Resep.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });
                   Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
               }
               pDialog.dismiss();       
               return serverResponseCode; 

               } // End else block 
             }
```

and this for uploadToServer.php:

```
    <?php
    include '../config/koneksi.php';

        $file_path = "adminweb/foto_berbagi_resep/";
            $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

            $link = mysql_connect($host,$database);
            mysql_query($link, "INSERT INTO 'gambar_upload' (gambar) VALUES('".$file_path."')"); /*or trigger_error($link->error."[ $sql]");*/
            mysql_close($link);

            }

            else{
                    echo "fail";
            }
   ?>
```

Comment: 1. Use PDO -> better for you safety. 2. do you get any errors or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like eugen says, use PDO or mysqli.
you can use mysqli very similar too the "old" mysql adapter.

```
$link = mysql_connect($host,$database);
mysql_query($link, "INSERT INTO 'gambar_upload' (gambar) VALUES('".$file_path."')");
mysql_close($link);
```

it should look like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd");
$filepath = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $file_path);
$query = "INSERT INTO 'gambar_upload' (gambar) VALUES('".$filepath."')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
mysqli_close($link);
```

another example can be found here: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thank you for this Stefan :)
after i've tried your code and now i can stored the image to my database.

Comment: my pleasure, you should always use **mysqli_real_escape_string** to **prevent sql injections**